# How to search places near a building in freebase?

Tags: java, geolocation, freebase

I'm made a web crawler that crawls into hotels websites and save Hotel name, hotel address and other stuff in a csv. After the csv is complete, I'd like to find attractions near the hotels, and to accomplish that I have to use Google Freebase and I can use the fields "Hotel Name" and "Hotel Address".
Looking inside the google documentations, the best thing I found is:

```
filter=(all type:restaurant (within radius:1000ft lon:-122.39 lat:37.7955))
```

This should search all restaurants in a radius of 1000ft, given lon and lat coordinates. So I should need something that, given the hotel name or the hotel address, returns me the geolocation of the building, or a way to build the query passing as parameters a street instead of geolocation.

Further searches didn't solve the clue.

Comment: another thing that could be useful to me could be finding the city name from the name of the building.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google Maps API to geocode the address: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/

Really any geocoding solution would work as that would give you the longitude and latitude.

Comment: that was one of the possibilities, but google maps api provide max 2500 requests per 24h, while freebase api let you make 10k per day.

Comment: Another option would be using Bing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701714.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had similar need to get the geolocation in the results.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/freebase/v1/search-output), I found that example:

```
filter=(all type:restaurant (within radius:1000ft lon:-122.39 lat:37.7955))
&output=(geocode)
```

And luckily, it works.

But frankly, those Semantic Web tools are SO rich/vast that it's really difficult to build queries.